# Javascript onclick insert value into array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an image map, with several areas defined. What I'm trying to do is get a value added to an array each time someone clicks on a specific area, and have the array displayed in real-time on the screen.

In my head section I have the array (not sure if this is correct):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var numArray = [];
</script>
```

Then I have somewhere in the body of the page

```
<p class="txt"><script type="text/javascript">document.write(numArray);</script></p>
```

The `<map>` areas are something like this:

```
<area shape="circle" coords="129,325,72" alt="1" href="javascript:numArray.push('1')">
<area shape="circle" coords="319,325,72" alt="2" href="javascript:numArray.push('2')">
<area shape="circle" coords="510,325,72" alt="3" href="javascript:numArray.push('3')">
```

So for example, if someone clicks on 1, then 2, then 3, I would like the array to display 123 in the `<p>`.

When I use this though, it doesn't add anything to the array (or at least the values aren't displaying).

Comment: use a for loop to go through the array printing out the values as you go or try numArray.toString();

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a function to your JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var numArray = [];
    function addNum(num) {
        numArray.push(num);
        document.querySelector(".txt").innerHTML = numArray.join('');
    }
</script>
```

Remove the script from the `<p>` tag

```
<p class="txt"></p>
```

And update the `<map>`

```
<area shape="circle" coords="129,325,72" alt="1" href="javascript:addNum('1')">
<area shape="circle" coords="319,325,72" alt="2" href="javascript:addNum('2')">
<area shape="circle" coords="510,325,72" alt="3" href="javascript:addNum('3')">
```

Comment: Works great. One question: Is there any way to get it to add numbers without commas in between? Right now it's showing 1,2,3 not 123.

Comment: Yeah, use `numArray.join('');` [Updated the answer to reflect that]

Answer (score 1):

`document.write` is only executed when the page is loaded. To write in element, is better to use `document.getElementById` (that require to add an id to your `<p>`), and also to replace the `href=` by an onclick event.

This looks like this:

```
<p id="pTxt" class="txt"></p>

<area shape="circle" coords="129,325,72" alt="1" href="#" onclick="addToArray(1);">
<area shape="circle" coords="319,325,72" alt="2" href="#" onclick="addToArray(2);">
<area shape="circle" coords="510,325,72" alt="3" href="#" onclick="addToArray(3);">
<script type="text/javascript">
    var numArray = [];
    function addToArray(num){
      numArray.push(num);
      document.getElementById("pTxt").innerHTML = numArray;
      return false;
    }
 </script>
```

Comment: isn't this almost exactly the same as my answer?

Comment: no, yours is much better because of the `join()`. Sorry I didn't see you answered before me

Comment: No problem, just making sure I didn't miss anything.